# Why Apache Spark's dataset API is not supported in Python, Java, Scala and SQL or R

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Apache Spark supports Data frame API in Scala, Java, Python, SQL, and R. Still, dataset API is only supported in Scala language so I want to know the main reason.

Comment: Probably opinion based. But. Codecs (`org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder`) are type classes. Type classes exist only in Scala (out of the languages listed). Encoding/decoding logic intensively explores Scala runtime reflection. Its specifics is that it's `TypeTag`-based i.e. persisting some compile-time information to runtime. Such compiler functionality also exists only in Scala.

Comment: Python and R are dynamically typed at all

Comment: The dannce between Feasibility, Complexity, Effort, Priority.

Answer (score 2):

> The Dataset API is available in Scala and Java. Python does not have the support for the Dataset API. But due to Python’s dynamic nature

From [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes) `Datasets` are supported in `Scala` and `Java` as well, and for `Python` and `R` are mainly dynamically typed